# Fetch data from database in php using angular js $http.get

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I am using angular js script to fetch data from external php file encoded in json in html page. I have used `$http.get(page2.php)` method to fetch json encoded array written in another file. But the problem is its not showing any output just a blank screen I dont know where am I doing wrong.

Here's `page1.html`

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('myctrl',function($scope,$http){
$http.get('page2.php').success(function(response){
$scope.names = response;
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>   
<div>
<table ng-app="myapp" ng-controler="myctrl" >
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
<td>{{ x.id }}</td>
<td>{{ x.name }}</td>
<td>{{ x.age }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's `page2.php`

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','practice');
if(!$con){
die("couldnt connect".mysqli_error);
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM records";
$result = $con->query($query);
$r = array();
if( $result->num_rows>0){
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$r[] = $row;
}
}
$res = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($r));
echo $res;
?>
```

I can't figure out where am I doing wrong.

Comment: You're error checking your connection, but not the query.

Comment: Is there any error on browser console ? Check your connection to database .Check by adding console.log(response);  in success callback

Comment: NO error just a blank screen

Comment: query is fine working good but it display nothing.. @JayBlanchard Blanchard

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure you're getting data from your query, you just need to send it as JSON. Add this before the `echo $res;` line:

`header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: it is showing the converted data when i run php file alone but as i call from html page it shows nothing. @kiswa

Comment: Try using something like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) and see what that shows when it calls the PHP file.

Comment: whats that for ?? @kiswa

Comment: It lets you test an API directly.

Comment: I am not using the api key...how would that resolve my issue.??

Comment: Not an API like that. It lets you call directly to your `page2.php` the same way Angular is calling it, so you can see what's getting returned from a client perspective. You may have a different return from that call than from just navigating to the page. That's why I gave you the above answer.

Comment: what is the problem with this code @kiswa . That's the simple thing why is it not working ? . I found this working on "  http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_customers_json " both are the same thing ..